# USB drive not recognized Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, usb-drive

I have a 16GB Hama usb stick and I'm using it on Ubuntu 14.04. Until yesterday it worked fine, but my Linux crashed and I had to copy some files on it using the low graphics interface. Anyways the files where copied and I reinstalled the system, but now I don't see my drive. Any other drives work.

This is what I get with `dmesg | grep -i usb`

```
[ 3028.034004] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 3038.195532] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 3054.355731] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 3054.523730] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 3064.685451] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 3522.645454] usb 2-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 3542.867682] usb 2-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3542.960989] usb 2-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6366
[ 3542.960994] usb 2-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3542.960998] usb 2-1.6: Product: Flash Card Reader/Writer
[ 3542.961000] usb 2-1.6: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 3542.961002] usb 2-1.6: SerialNumber: 058F63666438
[ 3542.961388] usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3542.962447] scsi10 : usb-storage 2-1.6:1.0
[ 3574.943893] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3585.105482] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3601.265555] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3601.433364] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 3611.594898] usb 2-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
```

This is what I get with `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4d51 Primax Electronics, Ltd 0Y357C PMX-MMOCZUL (B) [Dell Laser Mouse]
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:2110 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:1010 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And this is what I get with `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   229G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Result for `sudo fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00042ebd

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   480237567   240117760   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       480239614   488396799     4078593    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       480239616   488396799     4078592   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Do you have any ideea what is happening to my drive?

Comment: Have you tried formatting the pendrive using g-parted?

Comment: No, not yet. I would like to keep my data

Comment: Does it get recognized in any other OS?

Comment: No. I also tried on windows. It appears under control panel-> devices and printers but i cannot format it. I just tried with g-parted and it doesn't see it. I guess it time to put it in the trash...:(

Comment: Wait! let me see further if I can help you.

Comment: Is your pendrive visible in "Disk Utility"?

Comment: Yes, but i cannot format it. And it only appears sometimes. It doesn't matter witch usb port i plug it in

Comment: What does this command show in terminal: $ mount /dev/sdb /mnt ?

Comment: mount: /dev/sdb is not a valid block device

Comment: OK when you see your pendrive in "Disk Utility" what does it show beside the option "Device:"?

Comment: Multiple Card Reader

Comment: Nope it should show something like: sda or sdb or sdc

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was looking in the left menu. it's /dev/sdb

Comment: Were you been able to solve the problem? Thank you,
Kumar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As your pendrive is visible in "Disk Utility" and

```
mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

command returns

```
mount: /dev/sdb is not a valid block device
```

Therefore, your OS can detect the pendrive.

Now, open up terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type in the command:

```
sudo su
```

to get root privileges.

Next, type:

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1 && mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt -t auto
```

This got to solve the problem. But if it doesn't please comment below. Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Raphael, unfortunately this is what i get: /dev/sdb1: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you please try this: $ cd /dev
$ sudo MAKEDEV sdb

Comment: I did that. I have a folder names sdb1 in /dev but when I run the previous command again I get this: /dev/sdb1: No such device or address

Comment: ok then now are you able to format your pendrive in " Disk Utility"?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Try adding this line to fstab: /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb auto noatime,rw,users,exec,uid=1000,gid=100 0 0

Comment: Try this if you want to add something to fstab: "http://www.leonardoborda.com/blog/how-to-add-a-new-partition-to-the-fstab-file/"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15203/discussion-between-raphael-and-indra).

Comment: Did it work Indra?

Comment: No, the drive is busted. I ended up giving it to a friend who is into electronic and he opened it and said there is nothing to be done. Thank you for all your effort Raphael. Hopefully someone luckier than me will put your answer to good use

Comment: Sorry to hear. :'-(

Comment: `mount /dev/sdb` should (almost) never work, since `sdb` is not a partition. Usually the file system of a USB drive at `/dev/sdb` resides in `/dev/sdb1`. Alas since `mount` returned the error message, that sdb is no valid device (instead of it containing no known file system), that hints to a broken device anyway.

Comment: What does `mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb1` do? Would this not format your entire sdb1 partition as XFS and wipe any existing files off of it?

Comment: This command should never work , mkfs.xfs: command not found :)

Answer (score 4):

**MAKE SURE TO `DD` THE CORRECT DEVICE INSTEAD OF ZEROING OUT YOUR ACTUAL SYSTEM**

Completely zero out your USB device with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=4M
```

Then create a partition with a disk utility of your choice (`fdisk /dev/sdb`)

Then format the partition

```
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
```